# Add implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.1.0-alpha02" occurs Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-auto, android-studio-4.1

In build.gradle file, add this under dependencies

**implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.1.0-beta01"**

Then rebuild the project, it only shows

**:app:processDebugManifest >
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs**

No more error details.
I have checked AndroidManifest.xml

There is no any warnings or errors.

The following is my setting in build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30     
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30 
         ...
        
    }
    ...

    dependencies {
        implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.1.0-alpha02"
         ...
    }
}
```

`Android Gradle Plugin Version:3.3.2 Gradle Version:5.3`

Comment: use stable `implementation"androidx.car.app:app:1.0.0"`

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya,  I tried your solution, but occurred another error message.
Finally, I upgrade the developing environment.
AS: Bumblebee
Gradle Plugin version: 4.1.1
Gradle version: 6.7.1